# What is dummy filesystem?

Tags: command-line, 14.04, filesystem, disk-usage

I tried `df --help` command to generate the man-page for help on `df` command and I am stucked with a unknown term `Dummy filesystem`

This line in df manpage is where I get to know the term first time

`-a, --all             **include dummy file systems**`

Comment: just btw: manpages are accessed via `man` e.g. `man df`. not `--help`.

Comment: so what the result is same both generate the same information

Comment: so you're spreading misinformation. and no, they don't both generate the same information. manpages are much more complete and detailed. manpages are for when you have never used a command before, `--help` is for when you've just forgotten the exact argument name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df -a , -all
```

**-a** or **-all** option include in the listing filesystems that have a size of **0** blocks,
which are omitted by default.

Such filesystems are typically
**special-purpose** pseudo-filesystems, such as automounter entries.

Also, filesystems of type "**ignore**" or "**auto**", supported by some
operating systems, are only included if this option is specified.

Comment: what is the significance of 0 block size for partition?

Comment: @Creator it means that the "filesystem" doesn't correspond to a physical device. it is purely virtual. examples include e.g. /proc and /sys.